# How to improve this Regex?

Tags: regex

I wrote this regex to identify US type phone numbers:

```
\(?\d{3}\)?(-|\s)\d{3}-\d{4}
```

This works for phone numbers like:

217-244-2424 and
(217) 244-2424.

However it also works for unbalanced parenthesis like (217-244-2424

How can the regex be improved to make sure the parenthesis are balanced?
(I'm aware of the questions on regex phone numbers asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation), but I couldn't find what I was looking for from there.)

Comment: Why don't you just strip out the non-digits?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: @Blender: Yup! http://stackoverflow.com/a/123681/78845

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested it, but why not using the alternation operator ("|")? You could choose to have either both parenthesis, or none of them:

```
(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})(-|\s)\d{3}-\d{4}
```

Comment: Thank u. That was simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer you specific question on regex. You can try something like this to handle paranthesis:

```
^(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})$
```